# Which happens last, document.ready or document.ajaxComplete?

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to figure out what's the last event to execute on `DOM`. Is it `document.ready` or `document.ajaxComplete`?

Comment: The question doesn't make sense.  Loading the document is not an ajax event and I can't even find any reference for `document.ajaxComplete`.  jQuery's `$(document).ready(fn)` is triggered when the `DOMContentLoaded` event fires.

Comment: Your answer depends on whether or not there are AJAX events at all

Comment: @jfriend00 you can find reference on http://api.jquery.com/ajaxcomplete/

Comment: The answer for this is, .ajaxComplete can load before OR after document.ready. .ajaxComplete finishes executing after all ajax is completely loaded. By the looks of it, document.ready and ajaxComplete run at their own times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery's `$(document).ready(fn)` is triggered when the `DOMContentLoaded` event fires which occurs before the `window.onload` event.

Per MDN:

> The DOMContentLoaded event is fired when the document has been
>   completely loaded and parsed, without waiting for stylesheets, images,
>   and subframes to finish loading (the load event can be used to detect
>   a fully-loaded page).

Loading the document is not an ajax event and I can't even find any reference for `document.ajaxComplete` so that part of your question doesn't make any sense.

Comment: He's talking about this: http://api.jquery.com/ajaxcomplete/ (and yes, they're not comparable has @nasty has suggested)